# How to multiply matrices?

Tags: r

I want to know how to multiply two matrices in R language.

M1=[1,2,3
4,5,6
4,5,0]
M2=[4,5
6,7
9,8]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  A minimal amount of effort is expected for questions here - this one for example is easily searchable on this site or a search engine like google.  If that cannot solve your issue, you are asked to provide a minimal reproducible example including what you have tried already and an example of your desired output.

Answer (score 3):

You code example is not even R.  We do not use `[` to delineate matrices, nor do we use missing commas for dimension.  Try

```
> M1 <- matrix(c(1,2,3, 4,5,6, 4,5,0),3,3)
> M2 <- matrix(c(4,5, 6,7, 9,8), 2, 3)
> M1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    4
[2,]    2    5    5
[3,]    3    6    0
> M2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    6    9
[2,]    5    7    8
> M2 %*% M1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   43  100   46
[2,]   43  103   55
>
```

Dimensions have to be conformant. If you M2 is 2*3 you to transpose it, or use it on the left as I did here.  Using a transpose follows:

```
> M1 %*% t(M2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   64   65
[2,]   83   85
[3,]   48   57
>
```